# SVN shows differences immediately after a checkout, why?

Tags: svn

Immediately after I do an SVN checkout of a source tree, I run "svn diff" at the top level and see differences. What would cause this?

Comment: Ok, I see the problem, but don't kjnow the cure...The problem seems to only occur on a windows machine running with cygwin.  The files that get screwed up are files have have the same characters but different case.
So, for example yada_file.c and YADA_file.c end up getting quite confused in windows because filenaming ignores case.
Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Is your Subversion server on Linux? Subversion on Linux/Unix will consider `yada_file.c` and `YADA-file.c` as two different files, but on Windows, they're they same file. The only solution is not to have files with different casing on Windows or Macs. You can use a pre-commit hook to prevent users from adding files where the case name differs.

Comment: Yea, the server is Linux, but the client is windows.  Right, I don't have this problem when the client (doing the checkout) is Linux.  The complexity here is that these files are part of the Linux kernel source tree; so I was hoping there was some other way around this.  Just knowing what the issue is (didn't realize what was happening till about an hour after I posted the question) probably good enough because I'll never be building that portion of the tree on a windows machine anyway.